# How to get list of unseenUids in OenPop in vb

Tags: vb.net, email, pop3, openpop

I want to get list of all unseen emails or i want to check whether a email is read or unread in vb.

this is the code i am using.

Dim pop3Client As Pop3Client
        Dim uids As New List(Of String)

```
    Dim seenUids As New List(Of String)

    pop3Client = New Pop3Client
    pop3Client.Connect("pop.secureserver.net", 110, 0)
    pop3Client.Authenticate("KAP@grashauser.eu", "Selvam&&")


    Dim count As Integer = pop3Client.GetMessageCount

    Dim message As Message = pop3Client.GetMessage(2)


    MsgBox(message.Headers.From.DisplayName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The POP3 protocol does not have a way to get a list of the unseen messages. You have to keep track of that on your own.